# Programmatically picking up phonecall

Tags: sim-card

I have a door telephone on our office building. When somebody presses the button it calls a telephone number for which we have a simcard. Right now that simcard is in a cellphone. Everytime we have a meeting at our office, we have to pick up the phone and press `3` to open the door. I'm looking for a solution to be able to programatically pick up the phone and press the 3. Does any such software exist? I have googled but found nothing.

TLDR; I need some software (and a sim card reader) that can programmatically pick up the phone when it rings and respond with a `3` on the numpad.

The OS doesn't matter.

Not sure if Stackoverflow is the right place to ask. Let me know if you have suggestions for other better places to ask.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using the SIM Card in a normal 3G USB Dongle and an application called "[Gammu](https://wammu.eu/docs/manual/gammu/)" which can answer a call and sendDTMF codes i.e. number presses. I have only used Gammu on linux systems but I believe it works on Windows as well.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution:

1. Setup voicemail for that SIM card, and when you are asked to leave your voicemail message (the message which is played to whoever gets to the voicemail) just press the button #3.
2. When you want, use call forwarding to redirect all calls to the voicemail. Alternatively, turn off the phone (on most cellular networks this will redirect all calls to the voicemail).